# Xcode build failure due to Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native

Building failed with Xcode 13beta for React Native 0.64.2 project. It is on macOS Big Sur. The detail of error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_YogaKit in libYogaKit.a(YGLayoutExtensions.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_YogaKit)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What configuration change is needed to eliminate the error?

Comment: Quick google has the answer (read that and follow ) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733

Answer (score 19):

Create an empty swift file (####.swift) from Xcode in the main project which located Appdelegate.h file. This worked for my React Native project after Xcode version 13 update.

Comment: I followed this and it worked. But can you enighten me why this works?

Comment: Thanks. Have no idea why this worked.

Comment: I have added a void.swift in my main project, but still getting the same error

Comment: Xcode 13.2.1, RN 0.64.1: Indeed solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a new Swift empty file (it's not necessary to create a Bridging Header).

Answer (score 2):

Adding libswiftWebKit.tbd into Link Binary With Libraries build phase in XCode helped to solve the problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocSXs.png)